# Group by/Distinct column based on condition

Tags: java, sql, oracle, distinct

I am having a table with `child_entity_id`, `parent_entity_id` and `entity_name`. A parent can have multiple child. A child can be a standalone entity and may not have parent. In that case, parent column would be null.

Now, I need to execute a process on each parent. But if the parent is null, then need to execute it on child. How to fetch the necessary records from table?

```
Child_Entity_ID    Parent_Entity_ID    Entity_Name
    1011                  1000            xxx
    1022                  1000            yyy
    1033                                  abc
```

Now I need to execute two times. One for Parent: 1000 and another for standalone child : 1033.

Expected Result : Row #1 and Row #3.

Further Processing : Need to send the ID details and entity name to another shell script.

How to achieve this. Any help pls.

Comment: what is your required output

Comment: Is it just a SELECT statement with a LEFT JOIN you are looking for? What do you require to see i.e. output?

Comment: what do you want to do with this data? what process? expected output?

Comment: I need the entire row, say, from the given example, I need row #1 and #3. I don't need row #2. Then Process is to execute a shell script with the child_entity_id and entity_name and other few derived values

Comment: Edit the question and specify the expected result-set!

Comment: You explained it, but question is closed already. You can do it in several ways, shortest is analytic function with `first` option, like in this [dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1779ee0487b2e2182daec7483c6fc3f5).

Answer (score 1):

Hoping, I understood your question correctly. To get unique `Parent_Entity_ID` (in case of null then `Child_Entity_ID`)  you can check below query.

```
select distinct coalesce(Parent_Entity_ID, Child_Entity_ID) from table;
```